# Byzantium support in Jaxx wallet

Tags: wallets, jaxx, byzantium

Will the Jaxx mobile wallet support **ethereum** after Byzantium hard fork, after 16th October 2017? 
If not what other mobile wallet should I use for my **ethers**?

Thank you,